# Using the Azure CAF Terraform Module: How to manage AZure Firewall Policies (or Classic Rules) using the module?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

(for anyone who might be using the Hashicorp/Microsoft Azure CAF Module for enterprise infrastructure as code)

Azure provides a terraform module for implementing enterprise landing zones using infrastructure-as-code/data-as-code paradigm:

https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale

However there is no indication or documentation on how to manage Azure Firewall Policies and Rules using the module (but deploy of AFW is possible).

Has anyone done this using the module (or should I consider doing it using a separate module) ?

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, Azure CAF (aztfmod) and Terraform enterprise scale are two different solutions. This [Azure Landing Zone Comparison](https://www.meshcloud.io/2022/09/27/azure-landing-zone-comparison/) blog post explain the difference.

When you say you want to deploy firewall rules, I assume you want to deploy a [azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/), i.e. rules based on IP, Port, Protocol etc.

## Terraform Enterprise scale

Does not include support for deploying these fine grained `firewall_policy_rule_collection_group`. You can however configure `azurerm_firewall_policy` via the exposed variables described [here](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale/blob/2fff77ea6a8a0fbd6087ed9ec3c65b86daae3045/docs/wiki/%5BVariables%5D-configure_connectivity_resources.settings.hub_networks.md).

If you want to deploy a `firewall_policy_rule_collection_group` your best bet is to deploy that in your own module and connect it to the policy deployed by the enterprise scale module via `firewall_policy_id`.

## Aztfmod

In aztfmod, there's two places firewall rules come into place, depending on which [Level](https://aztfmod.github.io/documentation/docs/fundamentals/lz-intro/#level-2-core-platform-connectivity) of Azure CAF modules you're targeting

- Level 2: Core platform connectivity -> this is where you'd want to configure rules for your central hub
- Level 3: Application Landing zones vending machine -> if you offer e.g. on-premise connectivity to your subscription, you may need to configure additional firewall rules for each spoke network.

Here's an example how to configure the hub firewall rules in level 2
[examples/networking/firewall/103-firewall-policies/configuration.tfvars](https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/blob/main/examples/networking/firewall/103-firewall-policies/configuration.tfvars)

```
azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_groups = {
  group1 = {
    #firewall_policy_id = "Azure Resource ID"
    firewall_policy_key = "policy1"
    name                = "example-fwpolicy-rcg"
    priority            = 500

    application_rule_collections = {
      rule1 = {
        name     = "app_rule_collection1"
        priority = 500
        action   = "Deny"
        rules = {
          rule1 = {
            name = "app_rule_collection1_rule1"
            protocols = {
              1 = {
                type = "Http"
                port = 80
              }
              2 = {
                type = "Https"
                port = 443
              }
            }
            source_addresses  = ["10.0.0.1"]
            destination_fqdns = ["*.microsoft.com"]
          }
        }
      }
    }

    network_rule_collections = {
      group1 = {
        name     = "network_rule_collection1"
        priority = 400
        action   = "Deny"
        rules = {
          rule1 = {
            name                  = "network_rule_collection1_rule1"
            protocols             = ["TCP", "UDP"]
            source_addresses      = ["10.0.0.1"]
            destination_addresses = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"]
            destination_ports     = ["80", "1000-2000"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In general this seems to be closer to what you want.

Some caveat about both Microsoft Landing Zone approaches here.

Doing the integration between level 2 and 3 (in aztfmod language) is quite a bit complex and from my experience and can quickly become hard to keep track of doing manually which rules belong to which spoke. Consider implementing an automated (or at least semi-automated) [virtual network self-service](https://cloudfoundation.meshcloud.io/maturity-model/service-ecosystem/virtual-network-service.html) for spoke networks. This service can then build the firewall rule group variables for aztfmod dynamically for example.

Answer (score -1):

In [**this part of the documentation**](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale/blob/2fff77ea6a8a0fbd6087ed9ec3c65b86daae3045/docs/wiki/%5BVariables%5D-configure_connectivity_resources.settings.hub_networks.md) have information related to Azure Firewall configuration
[image: Azure Firewall]

Comment: Thanks for this response. However, this is this the global configuration of the firewall. What's missing from the documentation is how to: a) Add an FW App rule, b) Add a FW Network Rule c) Add NAT rules.